# ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 4 with pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pickle

I get this error

```
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 4
```

from this line of my code

```
full_df = pd.read_pickle('df_userID.pickle')
```

when running the script with python2.7

(on Ubuntu 14.04.5, 3.13.0-95-generic)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you provide `df_userID.head()` so it can be tested.

Comment: sure: here is the 1st row of the dataframe https://www.dropbox.com/s/ic7brs7tq5xpt7y/trial_copy.pickle?dl=0

Comment: How did you create your pickle file?

Comment: Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466523/python-how-to-handle-the-valueerror-unsupported-pickle-protocol-4-error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like this pickle file has been created like as follows:

```
pickle.dump(df, file_name, protocol=4)
```

or

```
pickle.dump(df, file_name, protocol=-1)
```

and Python 2.x accepts only protocols: 0, 1, 2

**Solution:**

either use Pandas pickling or a lower protocol version:

```
df.to_pickle('/path/to/df.pickle')  # preferred and version independent solution
```

or:

```
pickle.dump(df, '/path/to/df.pickle', protocol=2)
```

another option would be to use HDFStore (H5) or FeatherFormat - both options are very fast and reliable.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. It was created by one of my collaborator. Another solution is to just use python3, but there I have another issue - that's why I switched to python2. I have problem to update pandas after, I get this error `ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'
`

Comment: @jjrr, you may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371451/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-indexes)

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I did ..but it doesn't work. `pip3 show pandas` gives me still  0.13.1, while  `pip show pandas` 0.19.2

Comment: @jjrr, so consider using one of the following options: HDFStore, Feather or DataFrame.to_pickle()

Comment: - I managed to run the script on my mac...still I would like to solve that issue on the linux cluster, as it's faster ... When I run `pip3.4 install --upgrade pandas` I get a bunch of warnings, like `#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \`

Comment: i think you should open another question about how to update pandas on Linux... I would recommend to use [Anaconda distributive](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922569/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-indexes-in-ubuntu